# Ruby/Rails Debug in Aptana - rake not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rake, aptana

I am really excited today because today I found an error which no one else has found in the history of the internet.

I am trying to learn how to use Aptana Studio 3 for debugging so in my application's root directory, I right click on config.ru and click on debug server and this is what is produced on the console:

- List item

  - Fast Debugger (ruby-debug-ide 0.4.16, ruby-debug-base 0.11) listens on 127.0.0.1:50122
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/dependency.rb:247:in `to_specs'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `block in find_in_unresolved'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `map'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:451:in `find_in_unresolved'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:43:in `require'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/dsl.rb:1:in `'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:138:in `definition'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:126:in `load'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler.rb:110:in `setup'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/bundler-1.0.21/lib/bundler/setup.rb:17:in `'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `require'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:59:in `rescue in require'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:35:in `require'
  - C:/triton2/config/boot.rb:6:in `'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:55:in `require'
  - C:/triton2/script/rails:5:in `'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_load'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/lib/ruby-debug-ide.rb:112:in `debug_program'
  - c:/Ruby192/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.16/bin/rdebug-ide:87:in `'
  - c:/Ruby192/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `load'
  - c:/Ruby192/bin/rdebug-ide:19:in `'
  - Uncaught exception: Could not find rake (>= 0.8.1) amongst []

Also, in the terminal I get this:

> David@DAVID-PC /c/triton2
>
> gem install rake
>   Successfully installed rake-0.9.2.2
>   1 gem installed
>   Installing ri documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...
>   Installing RDoc documentation for rake-0.9.2.2...